# How to launch autorun apps on Windows without logging out and back in?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am creating a Windows application in VC++, when I launch it from Visual Studio CLI it works fine.

I want to make it start automatically at startup so I created a key in the registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. I can see in the task manager that the application starts, but it does not work properly (it is supposed to write to a file and nothing is written to the file).

Because of this, I need to log in and out of my Windows session every time I make a small change in order to debug it. It is a real pain because I have to restart all my development tools, browser, etc. and I lose ~20s every time.

My question is: is there a way to start all the applications that are supposed to run at startup (e.g. the ones with entries in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry key) without logging out and back in? For example a Powershell command?

I tried to look for answers on Google and MSDN but the only results I got are "How to make your app launch automatically at startup", which I already have figured out.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Create a schduled task that monitors that the applications in the Run regkey are running and restart them when they exits...